# How do I find out how to translate a Postman query in cURL via PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, postman

I use postman for the first time.

My goal is to download a JSON file.

I managed to look at the code for cURL in postman:

[image]

But if I test the code in the command line, I can not log in.

[image]

Actually, I want to call the JSON file via PHP. I have tested initial approaches. In addition to the problem that I can not authenticate myself here, I think that I need more values. For example POSTFIELDS. Is that correct and if so, how do I find what I have to enter in Postman? Here is my initial Code:

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.divessi.com/divessi/index.php",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "..",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic BASE64",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Postman-Token: TOKEN",
        "content-type: ??"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$obj = json_decode($response);

$events = array();
if ($obj)
{
    $events = $obj[0]->DATA;
}

$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err)
{
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        ... 
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Also, add content-type `application/json` in your cURL request.

Comment: The question is: Why am I getting an authentication error even though I copied the snipped from postman. Why can I log in to a different URL - but no JSON will be returned to me here. Only a String and and Number: DIVESSI - 1575025214 (See picture)

Comment: Are you uploading some file? You have content-type as multipart/form-data in your cURL command line request but nothing as such in the PHP code.

Comment: Yes, I think I have to enter something in POSTFIELDS. But first I have to manage to sign up.